# Write from stdin to stdout correctly like in bash

Tags: bash, go, wireshark, tcpdump

I need to realize an analog of bash command:

```bash
ssh -p 8022 root@${h} -i \~/.ssh/eve -C 'tcpdump -U -i '${i}' -w -' | /Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS/Wireshark -i - -k &
```

Here i lunched tcpdump command on foreign host and through pipe receving data of each packet in wireshark command. Its possible because of using flag -U in tcpdump. It waiting full packet and then send it to stdout, then via pipe to wireshark. And wireshark understand it and print each packet in online mode. Works fine! I need to implement this behaviour on Go.

Here what i try:

```go
func main() {

    Command := "ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.sbm n@127.0.0.6 -p 21057 -C \"sudo tcpdump -U -i any host 10.1.1.1 -w -\""
    cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", Command)
    stdout, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()

    reader := bufio.NewReader(stdout)
    go func(reader io.Reader) {
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(reader)
        for scanner.Scan() {
            os.Stdout.Write(scanner.Bytes())
        }
    }(reader)

    if err := cmd.Start(); nil != err {
        log.Fatalf("Error starting program: %s, %s", cmd.Path, err.Error())
    }
    cmd.Wait()
}
```

I builded it with name stdinoutExample and run:

```bash
./stdinoutExample | /Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS/Wireshark -i - -k 2>/dev/null &
```

Wireshark receiving data but dont understand it. It print some kind of garbage and complain that fields of packets are wrong..
So how i can correctly transmit data to wireshark like in Bash?

Answer (score 0):

Well i found correct way if someone interesting.

```
stdout, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()

PacketsChan = make(chan []byte)

go ReadChanOutStd()
PacketsChan <- PcapHead
go ReadfromBufferOutChan(stdout)

var (
    PcapHead = []byte{0xd4, 0xc3, 0xb2, 0xa1, 0x02, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x14, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00}
    PacketsChan chan []byte
)

func ReadfromBufferOutChan(R io.ReadCloser) {
    for {
        buf := make([]byte, 1024, 1024)
        n, _ := R.Read(buf)
        if n > 0 {
            d := buf[:n]
            res := bytes.Compare(d, PcapHead)
            if res != 0 {
                PacketsChan <- d
            }
        }
    }
}
func ReadChanOutStd() {
    for {
        select {
        case Buf := <-PacketsChan:
            os.Stdout.Write(Buf)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In case you're not aware of it, I thought I'd just mention [sshdump](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/sshdump.html), as it seems like it might be a better solution than the command you're using now.  I've never actually used it myself, so I can't offer any further insight about it, but I know it's available and seems like it might be a good fit here?